# Decoding Contract Log's "Data" field With eth-abi Throws Error: "Padding bytes were not empty: b'0x0000000000'"

Tags: events, python, logs

I used [this guide](https://codeburst.io/deep-dive-into-ethereum-logs-a8d2047c7371) to create the code below. I suspect the error is somewhat related to the encoding processes I do to the strings, as that is the only place where I deviate from the guide. Here is my code for decoding the contract's log's data field:

```
from sha3 import keccak_256
import json
import urllib.request
import ssl
import eth_abi

def format_raw_data(logs,event_name):
    abi = json.loads(json.loads(open("./abi.json").read())['result'])
    types = []
    names = []
    indexed_types = []
    indexed_names = []
    for elem in abi:
        if 'name' in elem and elem['name'] == event_name:
            for input in elem['inputs']:
                if input['indexed']:
                    indexed_types.append(input["type"])
                    indexed_names.append(input["name"])
                else:
                    types.append(input["type"])
                    names.append(input["name"])
            break

    for log in logs:
        encoded_topics = list(map(lambda x: str.encode(x), log['topics'][1:])) 
        indexed_values = [eth_abi.decode_single(t, v) for t, v in zip(indexed_types, encoded_topics)] #error occurs here
        values = eth_abi.decode_abi(types,log['data'].encode())
        print("Data: ", dict(zip(names,values)))
```

The thrown error is "eth_abi.exceptions.NonEmptyPaddingBytes: Padding bytes were not empty: b'0x0000000000'" Once the abi is downloaded into the same directory, the error should be reproducible.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the error is on the line you indicated? It really seems like it should be on one of the two following lines (the ones that call `eth_abi.decode_single` and `eth_abi.decode_abi`).

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad. Ill fix it right now

Comment: Without knowing the values for `abi`, `logs`, and `event_name`, it's hard to help much, but my guess is that you have a hexadecimal string where you're expected to have a bytes. If you can't debug it from there, you'll need to share a way for others to  reproduce the error.

Comment: I updated the question to include instructions for reproducibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a hexadecimal string where bytes are expected. The code works with a few small changes:

```
from eth_utils import decode_hex
...
for log in logs:
        encoded_topics = [decode_hex(topic) for topic in log['topics'][1:]]
        indexed_values = [eth_abi.decode_single(t, v) for t, v in zip(indexed_types, encoded_topics)] #error occurs here
        values = eth_abi.decode_abi(types, decode_hex(log['data']))
        print("Data: ", dict(zip(names, values)))
```